# Issue by using TestLink plugin in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testlink

I'm back on this tutorial to accomplish the last task I have to do in my project.
"Run a test from Jenkins and report results in TestLink"

Actually, i got a jenkins jobs which runs perfectly, it's running through maven and it's Junit RC Selenium tests.

But when i'm trying to connect with the TestLink plugin I got an error on the execution :

```
FATAL: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.Map
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.util.Util.castToMap(Util.java:586)
    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.TestProjectService.getTestProjectByName(TestProjectService.java:115)
    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.TestLinkAPI.getTestProjectByName(TestLinkAPI.java:438)
    at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.getTestLinkSite(TestLinkBuilder.java:255)
    at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.perform(TestLinkBuilder.java:140)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:717)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1502)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
```

When I go on the URL : `http://ip-address/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc.php`
I see : XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only.

I've connected the test-java-api through my pom file of the project :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>br.eti.kinoshita</groupId>
        <artifactId>testlink-java-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.6-0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Does anybody got an idea ?

Thanks in advance for your kindly help !

Comment: Ok, I fixed the first step by downgrading my testlink-plugin from 3.5 to 3.2 (I'm using TestLink 1.9.5) !
I know got some issues on "buildname" it seems that I have to indicate one but it sense to do be necessary..

Comment: Ok I fixed it by myself ! I just had to indicate a buildname, there's still a failure but it's probably due to configuration in testlink !

Comment: Hi @daguerrier, sorry to hear you're having problems with the plug-in. I'm testing it with TestLink 1.9.7 right now, and it seems to be working. Hope you have managed to get it working. All the best, Bruno